# Style Facebookand Google Login Button in Xamarin.Forms Portable Project

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, facebook-login, portable-class-library, google-signin

I'm developing an app for iOS and Android in Xamarin Forms and I've implemented the functionality for google and facebook login. I did that in the portable project and now I'm trying to style the buttons to look like the "Login with Facebook" button but the only style templates I found are for Android and iOS. I want to add the buttons to my MainPage.xaml so that the button is added to the view only there, but it is shown in the iOS and Android app.

Right now it looks like this without any style:

```
<Button x:Name="facebookLoginButton" Text="Facebook Login" Clicked="FacebookLoginButton_Clicked"/>
<Button x:Name="googleLoginButton" Text="Google Login" Clicked="GoogleLoginButton_Clicked"/>
```

There's a design guideline for the facebook [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/userexperience#buttondesign) but I'm looking for a library which makes it possible to add the buttons to the MainPage.xaml without styling the buttons on my own.

In short: I'm looking for the following Android layout code snippet for Xamarin Forms which I can use in the xaml file

```
<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
        xmlns:fb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/loginFacebookButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        fb:login_text="@string/loginFacebookButton"
        fb:logout_text=""
        style="@style/FacebookLoginButton"/>
```

Comment: For me it would also be ok if I can style the whole page in xaml and define the buttons in xml file of the android project and add them to the xaml file. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 ways of doing this :

You can do it the xaml way :

```
<Frame CornerRadius="3" BackgroundColor="#4167b2" HeightRequest="60" Margin="20" Padding="0" HasShadow="false">
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="5">
        <Image HeightRequest="80" Aspect="AspectFill" Source="http://3daystartup.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/facebook-logo-png-white-facebook-logo-png-white-facebook-icon-png-32.png" />
        <Label Text="Continue with Facebook" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontSize="20" FontAttributes="Bold" />
        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer x:Name="FacebookButton" AutomationId="FacebookButton" Command="{Binding FacebookButtonCommand}" />
        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
    </StackLayout>
</Frame>
```

You can do it the image way :

```
<Image HeightRequest="80" Aspect="AspectFill" Source="https://medyo.github.io/assets/images/facebook_connect_button.png">
    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer x:Name="FacebookImageButton" AutomationId="FacebookImageButton" Command="{Binding FacebookButtonCommand}" />
    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>
```

Both methods have `TapGestureRecognizer` to it so you can click on it

Comment: I like the first way and I'm gonna use it. Thank you! But I'm wondering if there isn't a xamarin facebook sdk for the pcl containting the button.

Comment: @papapple sorry no, Only on the services side using Identity Provider

Answer (score 0):

please find the best answer here using facebook SDK and dependency injection.

https://blog.xamarin.com/native-android-facebook-authentication-azure-app-service/

as in the link described.

1) Create Button as view in Shared library

```
public class FacebookLoginButton : Xamarin.Forms.View
{
}
```

2) Use it in xaml

```
</code><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:CoffeeCups.View;assembly:CoffeeCups"
             x:Class="CoffeeCups.View.LoginPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                     VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                     Padding="8">
            <Label Text="Login for Coffee!" 
                   VerticalOptions="Center"/>
            <controls:FacebookLoginButton/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

3) you need to have render as below in your android project. it similar code in IOS.

```
using CoffeeCups.View;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using CoffeeCups.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using Xamarin.Facebook.Login.Widget;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(FacebookLoginButton), typeof(FacebookLoginButtonRenderer))]
namespace CoffeeCups.Droid
{
    public class FacebookLoginButtonRenderer : ViewRenderer<FacebookLoginButton, LoginButton>
    {
        LoginButton facebookLoginButton;
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<FacebookLoginButton> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if(Control == null || facebookLoginButton == null)
            {
                facebookLoginButton = new LoginButton(Forms.Context);
                SetNativeControl(facebookLoginButton);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Bonus UWP:** this is not in the article but I achieved having native button in xamarin forms using [winsdkfb](http://microsoft.github.io/winsdkfb/auth/) library. basically your renderer in uwp looks like as below

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(FacebookLoginButton), typeof(FacebookLoginButtonRendererUWP))]
namespace CoffeeCups.UWP
{
    public class FacebookLoginButtonRendererUWP : ViewRenderer<FacebookLoginButton, FBLoginButton>
    {
        FBLoginButton facebookLoginButton;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<FacebookLoginButton> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control == null || facebookLoginButton == null)
            {

                facebookLoginButton = new FBLoginButton();
                SetNativeControl(facebookLoginButton);
                Control.Click += buttonClick;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Button layout in Xamarin.Forms

I got facebook s logo from here:
http://3daystartup.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/facebook-logo-png-white-facebook-logo-png-white-facebook-icon-png-32.png

Put inside ContentPage.Content tag

```
<Frame CornerRadius="5" 
               HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
               VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"
               BackgroundColor="#4167b2" 
               Margin="10" 
               Padding="5" 
               HasShadow="false">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Image Source="facebook" HeightRequest="32" WidthRequest="32" 
                       Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />
                <Label Text="Entre com o Facebook" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" 
                       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontSize="20" 
                       FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White" />

                <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding LoginCommand}" />
                </Grid.GestureRecognizers>    
            </Grid>
        </Frame>
```